# prevent user from entering negative sign and only 0 on angular input field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input

I have an input field where in when user type a number it will be automatically converted to a negative number which is being handled by `onInputChange`  but I don't want the user to manually or prevent them from inputting - (negative sign). So if they press - sign from the keys it should not be added on the input field.

Also I want to prevent user from typing only 0 and they are only allowed to input 0 if its after another number like they can input 50 , 6000, 100,000 etc. as long as it is not just a single 0

#html code

```
 <mat-form-field *ngIf="hasCashContribution === 'no'" appearance="fill" class="deal-form-date-picker opacity87" [ngClass]="{'enabled-input': hasCashContribution === 'no'}" style="padding-right: 16px;">
            <mat-label [ngClass]="{'alter-text-color': hasCashContribution === 'no'}">Payment</mat-label>
            <input matInput
              [(ngModel)]="cashContribution"
              (ngModelChange)="onInputChange()"
              class="alter-text-color"
              mask="separator.0"
              thousandSeparator=","
              [allowNegativeNumbers]="true"
              (keypress)="onKeyPress($event)">
            <span matPrefix class="alter-text-color" *ngIf="hasCashContribution === 'no'">$</span>
          </mat-form-field>
```

#ts code

```
 onInputChange() {
        if (this.cashContribution > 0) {
          this.cashContribution = -this.cashContribution;
        }
      }
      
      onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        // Check if this.cashContribution is null or undefined
        if (this.cashContribution == null) {
          return; // Do nothing if cashContribution is null or undefined
        }
      
        const inputValue = this.cashContribution.toString();
        const keyPressed = event.key;
      
        if (keyPressed === '-' || (keyPressed === '0' && inputValue === '0')) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be able to use the min attribute:

```
<input type="number" min="1">
```

But, here's another thought: you'll still need to write logic to verify input, even if you prevent bad input via key strokes.

The user could e.g. paste in bad values, or use some other means you've not thought of, which'll accept bad input and which might break your app... write a validator, and then display a suitable error message on what makes a value invalid.